# Converting string time to find difference in time from Time.now ~ Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the time of this format "20:10 PM", I need to find the difference between `Time.now` with the given time

For example If `Time.now` says `2022-05-17 18:32:52.133290553 -0700`, I need to find the difference between `Time.now` and "20:10 PM" for same-day today.

I am not able to find any references on Ruby on Rails for that.

Comment: _"I am not able to find any references on Ruby on Rails for that"_ – the docs for `Time` are a bit scattered. You have the [Ruby core docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Time.html), the [Ruby stdlib docs](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html) (which includes parsing) and several additions in the [Rails docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simple way:

```
>> Time.now - Time.parse("20:10 PM")
=> 10995.706874
```

`Time.parse` will assume today's date if it is not given a date. Returned result is in seconds.

Comment: If you need / want more control, there also `Time.strptime('20:10 PM', '%H:%M %p')` which takes an explicit format.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you always want to compare `Time.now` with a time from today (i.e 20:30 for today), you could construct a new `Time` instance for the time you're comparing.

```
todays_year = Time.now.year
todays_month = Time.now.month
todays_day = Time.now.day
time_to_compare =  Time.new(todays_year, todays_month, todays_day, 20, 30) # 20 and 30 represent the dynamic time you want to compare
time_diff = ((Time.now - time_to_compare) / 3600).round(2) # assuming you want to know the difference in hours and rounded to 2 decimal places
```